# Скрипт перестает работать, при перемещении кнопки на которой он стоит из расширенного шаблона в базовый

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Есть 2 шаблона, базовый (`base.html`, в нем находится только `navbar` и `footer`) и тот, который его расширяет(`search.html`). Я сделал в `search.html` кнопку, которая при нажатии проверяет состояние чекбоксов и основываясь на этом делает ajax запрос и выводит полученную информацию на экран,все работало, затем я решил переместить эту кнопку в `base.html`, после чего она перестала работать, не могу понять в чем проблема, ведь скрипт начинает работу уже при готовом DOM дереве, а значит для него никакой разницы вообще быть не должно.

Код функции и кнопки:

```js
"use strict"

function getAndShowItems() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "../item_list",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(itemsData) {
      let genderConditions = $('#genderSelector input.checked').map((index, domElement) => domElement.getAttribute('value')).toArray();
      let itemTypeConditions = $('#itemTypeSelector input.checked').map((index, domElement) => domElement.getAttribute('value')).toArray();
      // элементы с id genderSelector и itemTypeSelector находятся в search.html 
      genderConditions = Object.values(genderConditions);
      itemTypeConditions = Object.values(itemTypeConditions);
      let itemsToShow = itemsData.filter(function(element) {
        return (genderConditions.includes(element['gender']) && itemTypeConditions.includes(element['itemType'])) ? element : null
      });
      showItems(itemsToShow); // эта функция просто находит элемент с определенным id (в search.html) и выводит после него в немного украшенном виде данные на экран
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-light" type="submit" onclick="getAndShowItems()">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
                    <path d="M3.5 0c-1.93 0-3.5 1.57-3.5 3.5s1.57 3.5 3.5 3.5c.59 0 1.17-.14 1.66-.41a1 1 0 0 0 .13.13l1 1a1.02 1.02 0 1 0 1.44-1.44l-1-1a1 1 0 0 0-.16-.13c.27-.49.44-1.06.44-1.66 0-1.93-1.57-3.5-3.5-3.5zm0 1c1.39 0 2.5 1.11 2.5 2.5 0 .66-.24 1.27-.66 1.72-.01.01-.02.02-.03.03a1 1 0 0 0-.13.13c-.44.4-1.04.63-1.69.63-1.39 0-2.5-1.11-2.5-2.5s1.11-2.5 2.5-2.5z"></path>
                </svg>
</button>
```

JS код в виде встраиваемого скрипта, а не отдельного файла, пытался добавлять его и к `base.html` и к `search.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неработающая кнопка была обернута в тег `<form>`, поэтому при нажатии на нее все шло не так, если вынести кнопку за этот тег, то все снова будет в порядке